# binomial or hypergeometric random variable?

Tags: probability

I have $n=10.000$ items producted by a factory and I know that there are $m=150$ defective items amongst them.
The sample is composed of $k=100$ items.
I have to calculate the probability that my sample has $r$ defective items.

The solution that has been proposed it:

$$p=\frac{\binom{m}{r}*\binom{n-m}{k-r}}{\binom{n}{k}}=\frac{\binom{150}{r}*\binom{10.000-150}{100-r}}{\binom{10.000}{100}}$$

while my attemp was:

I determine the probability p that an item is defective
$$p=\frac{m}{n}=\frac{150}{10.000}$$
then I consider r as a binomial random variable with parameters p an n=100
and the probability that the sample has r defective items is:
$$\binom{100}{r}*p^r*(1-p)^{100-r}$$

Could someone give me an opinion about this solution?

Comment: Opinion: the proposed solution is correct. Your solution is not (see the answer to your question), but is a good estimate of the probability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Binomial means that all the trials are independent. In the solution corresponding to the binomial distribution, trials are not independent because r items are drawn without replacement. Thus every trial will not have same success probability.